# Как реализовать аналитику посещаемости сайта?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, аналитика, метрики

Всё время пользовался Yandex метрикой на сайте. Конечно сервис очень удобный, вся информация в доступном и удобном виде.

Но сейчас подумываю перейти на свою аналитику, без подключения сторонних сервисов. Думаю как это сделать.

Возможно есть какие-то готовые библиотеки, модули, пакеты ASP.NET Core, которые позволяют отслеживать запросы пользователей.

- наиболее популярные запросы
- с каких устройств сделан заход (мобильные, ПС, планшеты)
- браузеры
- с каких поисковиков пришёл человек
- ...

Когда делал первую версию сайта, сам реализовал подобную систему, но оказалось что она требует огромного времени на поддержание работоспособности и функциональности. Кроме того как я думаю это скорее всего было изобретение велосипеда. Полагаю есть какие-то готовые модули, которые можно использовать для подобных целей без подключения к сторонним сервисам и без передачи туда данных. То есть модуль который развёртывается прямо у меня на сайте.

Как другой вариант использовать сторонний сервис, но который не продаёт эти данные и не передаёт никому более. Возможно такое тоже есть, так как сейчас идеи приватности очень распространяются по миру. Если такой есть, то ищу варианты без оплаты.

**Обновлено:**
Мне не нужно прямо аналитика высокого уровня. Достаточно самых базовых показателей. По возможности что бы поменьше места занимало и попроще работала, без особой нагрузки на сервер.

Comment: Я знаю, что широко используется Zabbix. У нас собираются его прикручивать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Посмотрел у них на сайте. Удивило даже что Free, это очень круто. Правда пока немного отпугнуло что уровня Enterprize, мне нужны только базовые функции мониторинга. Но как вариант интересен. Может быть можно настроить только на сбор базовых характеристик.

Comment: Нашёл такой сервис https://www.app-metrics.io , пока не знаю собирает ли он нужную мне информацию, но выглядит интересно.